# Adjust the widths of text boxes in tkinter python for random numbers

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have the following codes for cloumn and row in my python program

```
def __init__(self):
    Frame.__init__(self)
    self.function = {0:self.bubble, 1:self.insertion, 2:self.selelction}
    self.master.title("Sorting")
    self.master.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
    self.master.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
    self.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S )
```

And for the text box for random numbers storing i used this code like having different text box for every digit.

```
def gen(self):
    self.nums = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(10)]
    for num in self.nums:
        i=iter(self.nums)
        item1=i.next()
        item2=i.next()
        item3=i.next()
        item4=i.next()
        item5=i.next()
        item6=i.next()
        item7=i.next()
        item8=i.next()
        item9=i.next()
        item10=i.next()
    #num = ''.join('%4i' % num for num in self.nums)
    self.text1 = Text(self,width=2, height=1)
    self.text1.grid(row =3,column=0,sticky = W+E+N+S)  
    self.text1.insert(END,item1)
    self.text2 = Text(self,width=2, height=1)
    self.text2.grid(row =3,column=1,sticky = W+E+N+S)  
    self.text2.insert(END,item2)
    self.text3 = Text(self,width=2, height=1)
    self.text3.grid(row =3,column=2,sticky = W+E+N+S)  
    self.text3.insert(END,item3)
    self.text4 = Text(self,width=2, height=1)
    self.text4.grid(row =3,column=3,sticky = W+E+N+S)  
    self.text4.insert(END,item4)
    self.text5 = Text(self,width=2, height=1)
    self.text5.grid(row =3,column=4,sticky = W+E+N+S)  
    self.text5.insert(END,item5)
    self.text6 = Text(self,width=2, height=1)
    self.text6.grid(row =3,column=5,sticky = W+E+N+S)  
    self.text6.insert(END,item6)
    self.text7 = Text(self,width=2, height=1)
    self.text7.grid(row =3,column=6,sticky = W+E+N+S)  
    self.text7.insert(END,item7)
    self.text8 = Text(self,width=2, height=1)
    self.text8.grid(row =3,column=7,sticky = W+E+N+S)  
    self.text8.insert(END,item8)
    self.text9 = Text(self,width=2, height=1)
    self.text9.grid(row =3,column=8,sticky = W+E+N+S)  
    self.text9.insert(END,item9)
    self.text10 = Text(self,width=2, height=1)
    self.text10.grid(row =3,column=9,sticky = W+E+N+S)  
    self.text10.insert(END,item10)
```

but its giving output like this shown below. how can i correct this.

[image]

Comment: A text box for every number seems rather excessive. Are you aware you can apply different colors to different ranges of text? If the only reason you are using multiple widgets is for coloring, either use multiple labels or a single text widget.

Comment: You ask how to fix it but don't define what "fix" means. Do you want each cell to expand equally, should they all stay two characters wide, or should they "shrink to fit"?

Comment: ya i want each text box to expand equally..like the last numbers are shown i want first 3 to be like them also

Answer (score 0):

According to a response to my comment, you want the widgets to expand equally. To do that when you are using grid, make sure each column has the same weight.

Here's an example, that also shows how you can create all of these widgets in a loop to cut down on the number of lines of code:

```
def gen(self):
    self.nums = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(10)]
    self.items = []
    self.text = []

    for column, num in enumerate(self.nums):
        text = Entry(self, width=2)
        text.insert(0, num)
        text.grid(row=3, column=column, sticky="nsew")
        self.items.append(num)
        self.text.append(text)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)
```

Notice how this example uses an `Entry` widget rather than a `Text` widget. Since you only want this one line tall, the `Entry` widget is the better choice because it always only allows a single line of text.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the textbox with 12 in it you can see that its size is related to the entire column and row (the cell above and below it are the same size), so that textbox--as well as your other "misbehaving" ones are going to stretch to match the formatting of their column. I would strongly suggest using the pack() function instead of the grid() for positioning in this situation, simply because it allows you to format each individual element without it necessarily affecting other elements. You could use a constant variable for the width/heigth of your textboxes and then set each of their attributes (width=WIDTHCONSTANT, height=HEIGHTCONSTANT), etc. Good Luck!

Comment: be careful with that advice -- they can't mix pack and grid in the same container. Using pack makes sense if they make the text widgets a child of a frame. Otherwise, they will have to switch their entire GUI  to use `pack`, which looks to be more work than is really necessary.

Comment: Yes this is true, I forgot to mention the no-no rule for mixing those, so thanks. However, I still think pack is a better way to go on this, even if it does require some grinding. Also I personally have found pack simpler to use, but that could be due to lack of use for the other methods like grid.